# Calculate average across all the branches for that day

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am currently struggling on how to calculate average across all the branches.

Like below you can see, call queue name is the unique name that has a call count for each day, multiple times a day.

I want to calculate the average call count across all the call queue names for each day to compare individual call name across the average of all the call queue names.

I am struggling for quite sometime and I was able to use averagex,

```
Per_day_count = AVERAGEX(VALUES(fAgentTimelineAnalytics[Call Queue Name]), 
CALCULATE(COUNT(fAgentTimelineAnalytics[Call Count])))
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below **Measure** code-

```
Per_day_count = 
AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        fAgentTimelineAnalytics,
        fAgentTimelineAnalytics[Date],fAgentTimelineAnalytics[Call Queue Name],
        "total", COUNT(fAgentTimelineAnalytics[Call Count])
    ),
    [total]
)
```

To consider all Branch you can use ALL which will clear ALL filter contexts-

```
Per_day_count = 
AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        ALL(fAgentTimelineAnalytics),
        fAgentTimelineAnalytics[Date],fAgentTimelineAnalytics[Call Queue Name],
        "total", COUNT(fAgentTimelineAnalytics[Call Count])
    ),
    [total]
)
```

Comment: There is one more column known as branch location, so what I want is the average to remain static when you filter for that branch location. Like static average calculated across ABC - XYZ branch when selected any branch like if I select branch ABC, it will still show static average for that day across ABC-XYZ.